# Deploy web app include testing in Glassfish using Maven2

Tags: maven-2, glassfish

Recently, I have used Eclipse and Oracle Glassfish server plugin to deploy my webapplications on the server.

However, I would like to do it in batch mode using Maven 2 and also do some testing before deploying.

I would like to do following tasks:

1. Get required dependencies (if any) from any repository (which shall I use?).
2. Run unit tests
3. If tests successful, deploy it

I am running Maven 2 and Glassfish 3.2.1

Can you support me with some example project including pom.xml file? Is there any knowledge resource for this kind of things?

Best regards

Comment: 'mvn clean deploy' is not helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you describes is very common.
Indeed, maven itselft will

> A Build Lifecycle is Made Up of Phases
>
> Each of these build lifecycles is defined by a different list of build phases, wherein a build phase represents a stage in the lifecycle.
>
> For example, the default lifecycle has the following build phases (for a complete list of the build phases, refer to the Lifecycle Reference):
>
> - validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
> - compile - compile the source code of the project
>     test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
> - package - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
> - integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
> - verify - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
> - install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
> - deploy - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.
>     These build phases (plus the other build phases not shown here) are executed sequentially to complete the default lifecycle. Given the build phases above, this means that when the default lifecycle is used, Maven will first validate the project, then will try to compile the sources, run those against the tests, package the binaries (e.g. jar), run integration tests against that package, verify the package, install the verifed package to the local repository, then deploy the installed package in a specified environment.
>
>   To do all those, you only need to call the last build phase to be executed, in this case, deploy:
>
>   mvn deploy

You should use the [maven glassfish plugin](http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/), and then execute

```
mvn glassfish:deploy
```

Here the full ewample from the official documentation :

```xml
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>${domain.username}</user>
                    <adminPassword>${domain.password}</adminPassword>
                    <!-- <passFile>path/to/asadmin/passfile</passFile> -->
                    <autoCreate>true</autoCreate>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <echo>false</echo>
                    <terse>true</terse>
                    <skip>${test.int.skip}</skip>
                    <domain>
                        <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                        <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                        <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                        <iiopPort>3700</iiopPort>
                        <jmsPort>7676</jmsPort>
                        <reuse>false</reuse>
                        <jvmOptions>
                            <option>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/login.conf</option>
                        </jvmOptions>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>server.log-service.file</name>
                                <value>${domain.log.dir}/server.log</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                        <auth>
                            <realm>
                                <name>testRealm</name>
                                <className>com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm</className>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>jaas-context</name>
                                        <value>test</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>file</name>
                                        <value>${project.build.outputDirectory}/keyfile</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </realm>
                        </auth>
                        <!-- <resourceDescriptor>path/to/resources.xml</resourceDescriptor> -->
                        <resources>
                            <connectionFactory>
                                <jndiName>jms/testQueueConnectionFactory</jndiName>
                                <type>queueConnectionFactory</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>UserName</name>
                                        <value>guest</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>Password</name>
                                        <value>guest</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>AddressList</name>
                                        <value>localhost:7676</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </connectionFactory>
                            <jmsTopic>
                                <jndiName>jms/testTopic</jndiName>
                                <destinationName>TestTopic</destinationName>
                                <connectionFactory>
                                    <jndiName>jms/testTopicConnectionFactory</jndiName>
                                    <properties>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>UserName</name>
                                            <value>guest</value>
                                        </property>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>Password</name>
                                            <value>guest</value>
                                        </property>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>AddressList</name>
                                            <value>localhost:7676</value>
                                        </property>
                                    </properties>
                                </connectionFactory>
                            </jmsTopic>
                            <jdbcDataSource>
                                <name>SomeDS</name>
                                <type>connectionPoolDataSource</type>
                                <poolName>SomePool</poolName>
                                <className>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource</className>
                                <description>Some JDBC Connection Pool</description>
                                <allowNonComponentCallers>false</allowNonComponentCallers>
                                <validateConnections>true</validateConnections>
                                <validationMethod>metaData</validationMethod>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>portNumber</name>
                                        <value>3306</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>password</name>
                                        <value>somePassword</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>user</name>
                                        <value>someUser</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>serverName</name>
                                        <value>some.host.somewhere</value>
                                    </property>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>databaseName</name>
                                        <value>SomeDB</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                            </jdbcDataSource>
                        </resources>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/artifacts/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean GlassFish Server 3.1.2 :-)

Using Maven with GlassFish documentation is covered in the Embedded Server Guide:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24932/embedded-server-guide.htm#gijhs

Hope this helps.